# How to keep the data consistent?

Tags: java, nlp

Suppose, I have an ArrayList aList1 with the following entries:
Mohandas Gandhi,
M Gandhi,
Martin Luther King,
Kim Jong,
Abrahm Lincln,
Kim Jng

Suppose, I have another ArrayList aList2 of all correct names. How can I match each item in aList1 with aList2?

I want the final output to be Mohandas Gandhi, Mohandas Gandhi, Martin Luther King, Kim Jong, Abraham Lincoln, Kim Jong.

The output should be without Spelling mistakes. How do I match the two words? If I can match two words, then I can use [Edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to convert one word to another word.

I need to code this in Java.

Comment: I'd like to clarify your question. Do you mean that you have 2 lists: one contains some words (names, whatever) that can be misspelled, second contains list of all available words written correctly. You have to "fix" misspellings in first list using the dictionary. Am I right?

Comment: @Saif ali Karedia - I have edited your question with useful information. If you accept the edit, it will make more sense for people to respond.

Comment: @saif-ali-karedia - Did you check any of the responses below?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should get you started:

```
String[] incorrectNames = "Mohandas Gandhi, M Gandhi, Martin Luther King, Kim Jong, Abrahm Lincln, Kim Jng".split(", ");
String[] dictionary = "Mohandas Gandhi, Martin Luther King, Kim Jong, Abraham Lincoln".split(", ");

List<String> correctedNames = new ArrayList<>();
for (String incorrectName : incorrectNames) {
    int distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    String closestMatch = null;
    for (String correctName : dictionary) {
        int currentDistance = levenshteinDistance(incorrectName, correctName);
        if (distance > currentDistance) {
            distance = currentDistance;
            closestMatch = correctName;
        }
    }
    correctedNames.add(closestMatch);
}

return correctedNames;
```

You will of course need an implementation of `levenshteinDistance`. Other caveats: the algorithm is `O(m*n)` where `m` is the size of the dictionary and `n` is the number of names to be corrected, and the Levenshtein distance *might* be too simple to do this well.

Comment: I'd recommend you to refer to existing Java implementation of Levenshtein distance to complete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**How to approach such problems?**

While I think there may be a number of ways to do it, I think the simplest one is to determine the **similarity** or *Fuzzy test*. And using `Levenshtein distance` you can determine how much % you will need to change one string to convert to the other. You can then apply filters to determine which one is close. In my case, I have used apache commons StringUtils to give me the **Edit Distance** value.

EDIT: 
**What kind of filtering criteria can be setup?**

You have to setup your own rules for filtering.

1. Ignore results where the percentage match is less than 50%.
2. Treat the percentages as ordinary numbers, and sum them to create a "total match" between the search terms and document.

In the example code below, I have only used #1. Although, I did not ignore anything as the data points matched.

But imagine, "Money Laundering" and "Money Facts", and the user searches for "Mony Lawndaring".

**Word 1**          **Word 2**      **Match**

Mony                Money           80%

Mony             Laundering         10%

Lawndaring          Money           10%

Lawndaring          Laundering          80%

Total match for "Mony Lawndaring" against "Money Laundering" is 160.

Mony Lawndaring vs Money Facts

**Word 1**  **Word 2**  **Match**

Mony    Money   80%

Mony    Facts   0%

Lawndaring  Money   10%

Lawndaring  Facts   10%

Total match for "Mony Lawndaring" against "Money Facts" is 80.

**Result**

Then by simply ordering the search results by the highest total match, we can see the "Money Laundering" document appear before "Money Facts" in the search results list!

```
package algorithms;

import org.apache.commons.lang.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LevenshteinDistance {

    public static double similarity(String s1, String s2) {
          String longer = s1, shorter = s2;
          if (s1.length() < s2.length()) { // longer should always have greater length
            longer = s2; shorter = s1;
          }
          int longerLength = longer.length();
          if (longerLength == 0) { return 1.0; }
          int distance = StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(longer, shorter);
          return (longerLength - distance) / (double) longerLength;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> aList1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Mohandas Gandhi", "M Gandhi", "Martin Luther King", "Kim Jong", "Abrahm Lincln", "Kim Jng"));
        ArrayList<String> aList2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Mohandas Gandhi", "Martin Luther King", "Kim Jong", "Abrahm Lincln"));
        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String incorrect : aList1){
            for (String correct : aList2){
                if (similarity(incorrect, correct) > 0.5){
                    System.out.println("Match found with similarilty more than 50% between :" + incorrect + " from first list and " + correct + " from second list" );
                    output.add(correct);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Output: ");

        for (String out : output){
            System.out.println(out);
        }   
    }
}
```

---

**Result:**

Match found with similarilty more than 50% between :Mohandas Gandhi from first list and Mohandas Gandhi from second list

Match found with similarilty more than 50% between :M Gandhi from first list and Mohandas Gandhi from second list

Match found with similarilty more than 50% between :Martin Luther King from first list and Martin Luther King from second list

Match found with similarilty more than 50% between :Kim Jong from first list and Kim Jong from second list

Match found with similarilty more than 50% between :Abrahm Lincln from first list and Abrahm Lincln from second list

Match found with similarilty more than 50% between :Kim Jng from first list and Kim Jong from second list`

**Final Output Array:**

Mohandas Gandhi
Mohandas Gandhi
Martin Luther King
Kim Jong
Abrahm Lincln
Kim Jong

Comment: What if i have M K Gandhi and Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi ? Match will be less than 50% i guess. How to approach this case?

Comment: Added response in the EDIT section to your question. essentially, you will need to Treat the percentages as ordinary numbers, and sum them to create a "total match" between the search terms and document.